# Webフロントエンドでオブジェクト指向で開発する方法

Tags: vue.js, framework

業務でVue/Vuexを利用しているのですが、OOPに慣れているため、以下の点で違和感や不便を感じます。

・親コンポーネントから子コンポーネントへの通信をデータの変化(props)で行うという基本思想
・コンポーネントのメソッドを外部から呼び出せるが、非推奨であること
・コンポーネントのdataやmethodsなどをprivateにできないこと
・Vuexがシングルトンなためグローバル変数化してしまい、関心の分離がしづらいこと

そこで、オブジェクト指向なクライアントサイドのフレームワークやライブラリがあれば、ぜひ教えていただきたいです。言語は問いませんし、wasmなどでも結構です。

よろしくお願いします。